# Every element of a matrix with \displaystyle

Tags: math-mode, matrices

Is there a way to make every element of a matrix to be `\displaystyle`? I tried many approaches but  changes happened within a matrix environment. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \begin{matrix}
      \lim_x 
    \end{matrix}

\end{document}
```

I want the math operator to have the same limits position with displaystyle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to proceed as follow :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $
        \begin{matrix}
             {\displaystyle \lim_x}
        \end{matrix}
    $
\end{document}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: This method will not have the desired effect if the `amsmath` package happens to have been loaded with the option `nonamelimits`. More importantly, the instruction `\displaymath` will have to be inserted at the start of each and every cell that's supposed to contain "enlarged" material (sums, integrals, limit-like operators, etc).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\makeatletter
\def\env@dmatrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \extrarowheight=2ex
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols{>{\displaystyle}c}}}

\newenvironment{dmatrix}
  {\env@dmatrix}
  {\endarray\hskip-\arraycolsep}

\newenvironment{bdmatrix}
  {\left[\env@dmatrix}
  {\endmatrix\right]}
% and other matrix environments are similar
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bdmatrix}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 & a=b \\
\frac{1}{2} & c=d
\end{bdmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{dmatrix}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
\end{dmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

But don't abuse display style, please.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that applies displaystyle-math *automatically* in `pmatrix` and `bmatrix` environments. It should be obvious how the setup may be extended to other math environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'pmatrix' and 'bmatrix' environments    

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\AtBeginEnvironment' macro
\AtBeginEnvironment{pmatrix}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}

\begin{document}
$\lim_n$,       % textstyle
$\begin{pmatrix}
      \lim_n    % automatic displaystyle
\end{pmatrix}$, 
$\begin{bmatrix}
      \lim_n    % automatic displaystyle
\end{bmatrix}$, 
$\lim_n$        % back to textstyle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution using [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). Note you'll have to write the same command for every type of matrix environment. I also use the [`nccmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) package to use `\mfrac` (medium-sized fractions), a `\dfrac` in a matrix would be too big, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix*}{\apptocmd{\lim}{\limits}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\noindent $ \lim_{x\to 0}\mfrac{\sin x}{x} = 0 $
\begin{flalign*}
  & \text{With \texttt{\textbackslash mfrac}: } & & \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
  \lim_{x\to 0}\mfrac{\sin x}{x} = 0\\[2ex]
  \lim_{x\to 0}\mfrac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} = \mfrac{1}{2}\\[-2ex]\
  \end{bmatrix*} & \\[2ex]
  & \text{With \texttt{\textbackslash dfrac}: } & & \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
  \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 0\\[2ex]
  \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\\[-2ex]\
  \end{bmatrix*} &
\end{flalign*}
$\lim_{x\to 0} \mfrac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} = \mfrac{1}{2} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if we could match the size of operator 'limit' and its operand. Clearly, there is a mismatch pattern of size here

Comment: That's an aesthetic choice. In my updated answer, you can compare between \mfrac (~ 80 % of `displaystyle) and \dfrac.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for pointing that; I'll correct at once.

Comment: I tried this: \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u_{2D}}{\partial r}\\\dfrac{1+\omega^2r^2} r\dfrac{\partial u_{2D}}{\partial\varphi}\end{pmatrix}=0. The upper indices of the second row overlap with bottom of the first. Making everything display style has the same effect, maybe just a little less. Typed in Word this math actually looks much better :D.

Comment: @facetus: Row spacing in LaTeX is often too tight. You can add `cellspace`  to your preamble, like this: `
\usepackage[math]{cellspace} 
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}`.