# displaystyle for every entry in matrix

Tags: matrices, displaystyle

I have a matrix whose entries are limits and I would like to have the `\displaystyle` rendering without having to put it in front of every entry.

Is there some equivalent of the optional `enumerate` argument `[before={\everymath{\displaystyle}}]` ?

[The accepted answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260408/displaystyle-for-a-part-of-the-document) (in which the optional enumerate argument is explained) seems to suggest that I could just write:

```
\begin{matrix*}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
% entries of matrix, all of which to be rendered in \displaystyle fashion.
\end{matrix*}
```

But this did not work for me. Can this be done?

Comment: Please post a full compilable MWE.

Comment: Off-topic: *A* matrix with only four entries? It seems easiest to just put `\displaystyle` everywhere, or if they all contain limits, just define `\newcommand{\dlim}{\displaystyle\lim}` and use `\dlim`, rather than trying to automate such a small instance of usage.

Comment: @Werner not really about this particular matrix (& no, not just 4 entries) - I just discovered the `enumerate` argument and then ran into this issue and wanted to know if similar functionality already existed.

Comment: NB It looks like my question is a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215663/every-element-of-a-matrix-with-displaystyle?rq=1), but it didn't come up in searches or as a proposed question. Furthermore, the answers here are different (& more helpful to me). Not sure how that should be handled, but thought it should be flagged to the mods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the `displaystyle` globally, add `\everymath{\displaystyle}` to the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix*}
%
1\int & 2\sum \\
%
3 & 4
\end{matrix*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Or, you can use it locally as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

{
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix*}
%
1\int & 2\sum \\
%
3 & 4
\end{matrix*}
\end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for illustrating proper use of the begin/end group for the `\everymath{\displaystyle`, exactly what I was trying to understand!

Comment: Wow, I used to prepend `\displaystyle` before every fraction in `matrix` env. `\everymath{\displaystyle}` really saved my life. :D

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what this would be for; anyway, here's an implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\makeatletter
\def\env@dmatrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \def\arraystretch{2}%
  \array{*{\c@MaxMatrixCols}{>{\displaystyle}c}}%
}
\newenvironment{dmatrix}{\env@dmatrix}{\endmatrix}
\newenvironment{pdmatrix}{\left(\env@dmatrix}{\endmatrix\right)}
\newenvironment{bdmatrix}{\left[\env@dmatrix}{\endmatrix\right]}
\newenvironment{Bdmatrix}{\left\{\env@dmatrix}{\endmatrix\right\}}
\newenvironment{vdmatrix}{\left|\env@dmatrix}{\endmatrix\right|}
\newenvironment{Vdmatrix}{\left\|\env@dmatrix}{\endmatrix\right\|}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bdmatrix}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x} & 1 \\
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx & \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{bdmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]